# Should library and media files be stored in the repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm using SVN but this question is related to any version control system.

When developing an application that uses media files(images, videos, xml files etc) that are constantly changed and almost every application version (or revision) is using a unique set of these media files which are not compatible with previous (or future) versions of these files. When this application uses certain versions of third party libraries which are incompatible with their previous or future versions. Is it a common practice to store all these binary files in the repository, e.g. SVN?

I think yes.

Pros:

- If the project is big and some functionality was broken in it or a bug have appeared you can always do an "Update to revision" and find that place where the bug appeared. And fix it.
- Making checkout and building the application is easy, because you have everything you need in your working copy to build the application

Cons:

- SVN server will need much HDD space to store all the versions. Somebody says that it becomes sluggish
- SVN Updates are slow

Are there any other advantages of storing only source code files in the repository?

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for images, videos and XML files, but we store third-party libraries in a separate SVN repository, with everything in the trunk.  It works great.

Developers can check it out to their local machines, or fetch the files they need at compile-time over the network.  We've modified our Visual Studio project files to point to a local environment variable, which links the binaries in the SDK to wherever they happen to be.

Assuming the files are in a local working copy called OURSDK, the environment variable would be:

```
>set OURSDK
OURSDK=C:\Source\OURSDK
```

Then we modified our C# and C++ project files to use these macros instead of relative paths:

```
AdditionalIncludeDirectories="&quot;$(OURSDK)\log4cxx\src\main\include&quot;$(OURSDK)\xerces-c\include&quot;;&quot;$(OURSDK)\TSE-RegExp\Include&quot;"
```

We maintain three versions of our product this way, and linking against third-party libraries is almost never an issue.  The only minor hitch is that the repo is effectively "write-only", where libraries go in and stay there, so it's slowly getting bigger over time.  Totally worth it. :)